# Isuues with passing image to a view controller to be used for a network POST request

Tags: swift, xcode, closures, swift5

I have a question please, i am trying to create a small app that involves me sending a POST request with an image to an API. I put all my networking logic in a separate swift class and i have a main view controller. The problem i have is that i need to get an image from my main viewcontroller and send it to the separate networking class so it can be sent with the POST REQUEST but i have been having issues doing this as the image value returns null on transfer to the networking class. I have tried using closures, delegates, properties to try and transfer this image to no success. iF i do all networking in my main viewcontroller, everything works fine but i will like to separate the networking logic. I have been on this for two days, PLEASE help suggest what i am missing or the best way to go around this.

```
import UIKit
import YPImagePicker


class NewViewController: UIViewController {
static let instance = NewViewController()

var config = YPImagePickerConfiguration()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        config.isScrollToChangeModesEnabled = true
        config.onlySquareImagesFromCamera = true
        config.usesFrontCamera = false
        config.showsPhotoFilters = false
        config.showsVideoTrimmer = true
        config.shouldSaveNewPicturesToAlbum = true
        config.albumName = "DefaultYPImagePickerAlbumName"
        config.startOnScreen = YPPickerScreen.photo
        config.screens = [.library, .photo]
        config.showsCrop = .none
        config.targetImageSize = YPImageSize.original
        config.overlayView = UIView()
        config.hidesStatusBar = true
        config.hidesBottomBar = false
        config.preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
        config.bottomMenuItemSelectedTextColour = UIColor()
       config.bottomMenuItemUnSelectedTextColour = UIColor()
       // config.filters = [DefaultYPFilters...]
        config.maxCameraZoomFactor = 1.0

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func sendBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        NetworkServices.instance.userChoice { (Age) in
                   print(Age)
               }
    }

    @IBAction func imageBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let picker = YPImagePicker(configuration: config)
    picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, _ in
        if let photo = items.singlePhoto {
            self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            self.imageView.image = photo.originalImage


        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)





}

    func getimages(completion: @escaping(UIImage) -> ()) {
        completion(imageView.image!) // THIS IS WHERE I USED CLOSURES TO SEND MY IMAGE.
    }


}
```

//The below is my networking class which uses POST method, the post method works but this class //never receives the image from the main viewcontroller class.

```
import UIKit
typealias Parameters = [String: String]
class NetworkServices {



    static let instance = NetworkServices()

    func userChoice(completion: @escaping (Float) -> ()) {

       NewViewController.instance.getimages { (image) in

            guard let mediaImage = Media(withImage: image , forKey: "inputFile") else { return } //This is where you manually change things, insert your image and the key

                                         guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.cloudmersive.com/image/face/detect-age") else { return }
                                         var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                                         request.httpMethod = "POST"

                        let boundary = self.generateBoundary()

                                         request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                                         request.addValue("f6-4e94-8b-e4f1", forHTTPHeaderField: "Apikey")

                        let dataBody = self.createDataBody(withParameters: nil, media: [mediaImage], boundary: boundary)
                                         request.httpBody = dataBody

                                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                                        if error != nil{
                                            debugPrint("Errors were found")
                                            return
                                        }

                                             guard let data = data else{ return }

                                            do {
                                                 guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else { return }

                                              guard let outputs = json["PeopleWithAge"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

                                                 var requiredAge = [Float]()

                                                 for ages in outputs {
                                                     let age = ages["Age"] as? Float ?? 0.0
                                                    requiredAge.append(age)


                                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                        completion(age)
                                                    }



                                                 }



                                             } catch {
                                                 debugPrint("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                             }
                                             }
                                       task.resume()

        }

    }




    //MARK: - Post Methods

    func generateBoundary() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }

    func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {

        let lineBreak = "\r\n" //this is required in converting my file into data
        var body = Data()

        if let parameters = params {
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
            }
        }

        if let media = media {// put in your filename here from media class
            for photo in media {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.filename)\"\(lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append(photo.data)// append actual image from Media class when you initialise Media class
                body.append(lineBreak)
            }
        }

        body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

        return body
    }


}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) { // i will use this to append all my files.
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but it would help if you decoupled your code. Don't rely on the image view to store an image that you upload. Make an image picker that can pick an image and gets its data. Make a view that can display image data and make a separate uploader that can upload image data. The three of these should be separately testable and should all work independently.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, what do you mean by a view that can display image data and also a separate uploader? can you direct me to resources where i can read up on this please?

Comment: Read about [unit testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UnitTesting.html). You should be able to write a unit test that runs without any UI to test your image uploading code. Once you have that working it should be easy to integrate into any UI

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this.